# Pass a bash script command-line option from a Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have a bash script that is run as part of a Dockerfile build process.

my_script.sh

```
poetry install
```

Dockerfile

```
RUN ./my_script.sh
```

What I would like to do is optionally invoke `poetry install -vvv` when I build the Docker image.

I tried something like:

Dockerfile

```
ARG POETRY_OPTION="-vvv"
RUN ./my_script.sh ${POETRY_OPTION}
```

and my_script.sh

```
poetry install $1
```

But that isn't being honored. It runs as if that option is not there.

It seems to me that maybe that works for regular arguments, but won't work for "options".

Comment: Please [edit] the post and show the full `Dockerfile`.

Comment: The unquoted `$1` is a bug which manifests if you try to pass in something which contains shell metacharacters. The proper idiom is `"$@"` which means "all the arguments, properly quoted".

Comment: @tripleee : Correct, but in this concrete example, where the option is said to a plain _install_, the plain $1 should do as well, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the ARG inside of the Dockerfile as `ARG POETRY_OPTION`. While running the docker build command use `docker build --build-arg POETRY_OPTION="vvv" .`